# Railstutorial.org Michael Hartl chapter 9 exercise 3 "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have started to learn Rails, and I got stuck on chapter 9 third exercise.

The **exercise** looks like this:

```
  test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              FILL_IN,
                                            password_confirmation: FILL_IN,
                                            admin: FILL_IN }
    assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin?
  end
```

My problem is the `last Fill_IN >>     assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin`?

`@other_user` is taken from Fixture and looks like this:

```
archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

`Update action` looks like this:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I also added `:admin` to the user_params so the `:admin param` could be modify:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :admin)
end
```

The answer I thought was correct was:

```
  test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch :update, id: @other_user, user: { password:              @other_user.password,
                                            password_confirmation: @other_user.password_confirmation,
                                            admin: true }
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
  end
```

But it looks like the @other_user is not being modified, so I think that error is in last assert.

My answer is wrong, I can't get this test to failed, it is because in last assertion  `"assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin?"`

I don't know what to put in the FILL_IN section. I tried to cut off FILL_IN but this doesn't work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: assert_not @other_user.FILL_IN.admin? << What to put in FILL_IN to make this test filed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must reload the instance variable after making changes to the underlying record. This will load in the new changes.

```
assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, with a 4th edition of the tutorial, using Rails 5.0.0, my answer is:

```
test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
  log_in_as(@other_user)
  assert_not @other_user.admin?
  patch user_path(@other_user), params: {
                                  user: { password:              "",
                                          password_confirmation: "",
                                          admin: true } }
  assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
end
```

The password and password_confirmation field can be left blank, imho; as is shown in another example, Listing 10.11 (in the Rails 5 edition).

Answer (score 0):

One more thing about your code -- I'm working through the Hartl tutorial, too, and I think if your password in the `PATCH` request is set to `@other_user.password` (as well as the password confirmation), then your test will be green even if `:user` is permitted in the `user_params`, and the test should actually be red at that point.

This happens because `:archer` in your `users.yml` fixtures file doesn't have a `:password` attribute; he only has `password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>`, and you can't un-hash a password once it's been hashed, like his has.

Just change the entries to

```
{ password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password' ... }
```

and the tests should test for the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, according to the above help, this should be the correct answer：

```
  test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch user_path(@other_user), params: { user: { password:                  'password',
                                                    password_confirmation:     'password',
                                                    admin:                      true } }
    assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
  end
```